# Django request.POST returning NONE

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views, crud

I have been working on a Django REST API and one of the views is as follows :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create(request):
    key = request.POST.get('key')
    name = request.POST.get("name")
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    print(key)
    if(key=='0'):
        user = Users(name=name,email=email,password=password)
        user.save()
        return Response("User Created Successfully")
    else:
        return Response("Invalid Key")
```

When I send a POST request with all the proper parameters I get the **key** printed as **NONE**, but I tried replacing POST with GET every where as below and then sending a GET request actually works normally, but POST request isn't working :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def create(request):
    key = request.GET.get('key')
    name = request.GET.get("name")
    email = request.GET.get("email")
    password = request.GET.get("password")
    print(key)
    if(key=='0'):
        user = Users(name=name,email=email,password=password)
        user.save()
        return Response("User Created Successfully")
    else:
        return Response("Invalid Key")
```

Thanks in advance !!

Tried GET instead of POST and that works, but since this is a method to enter value in the DB so this should be POST request.

**[Edit 1]**

I have tried using request.data but that isn't working, it is returning empty request like this {} and the same is the case with request.POST.

I am sending the request from Postman.
The request I am sending is like this :

[image]

Comment: From where are you sending the POST request? Include it as well

Comment: Have you tried `request.data` ?

Comment: Please share get and post request too.

Comment: I have tried request.data but that is empty {}.

Comment: I have shared the request I was sending to the API in the edited question above now. I had been sending it using POSTMAN

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for helping, the mistake was that I was passing the arguments in PARAMS instead of BODY tab in POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot, you are passing query parameters in `POST` request. You should `POST` data though data tab in postman (formdata,json,etc). Based on your screenshot, you can get the data passed through `request.query_params`, but this is not recommended for `POST` requests.

In Django REST Framework, `request.POST` or data submitted through `POST` is restructured into `request.data` and data through `GET` requests is passed into `request.query_params`. Both of these are `QueryDict`, so normal dictionary methods are applicable.

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing

Comment: I tried request.data and I printed it and it is {}

Comment: You are passing query params in `POST`. For query parameters, you should use `request.query_params`. For sending `POST ` requests, you should go to the `Body` tab in your postman and add data there.

Comment: Yes, now I understood.